# Let's get critical: Jan 2014 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Space Exploration Stack Exchange](http://space.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://space.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Final Results

- [Do lunar landers communicate with ground stations during descent and landing?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/3134/do-lunar-landers-communicate-with-ground-stations-during-descent-and-landing)

**Net Score: 9** (Excellent: 9, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [At what angle did Apollo 13 need to reenter?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/3058/at-what-angle-did-apollo-13-need-to-reenter)

**Net Score: 8** (Excellent: 8, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [How long does it take for a satellite to reach GEO?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/2914/how-long-does-it-take-for-a-satellite-to-reach-geo)

**Net Score: 8** (Excellent: 8, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Conjunction analysis for deep space missions](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/3067/conjunction-analysis-for-deep-space-missions)

**Net Score: 5** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Could electricity propel Curiosity on Venus?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/3037/could-electricity-propel-curiosity-on-venus)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Can I derive a combined equation for velocity of solar sail?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/2997/can-i-derive-a-combined-equation-for-velocity-of-solar-sail)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [How are fuel leaks discovered on a rocket?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/2987/how-are-fuel-leaks-discovered-on-a-rocket)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Does NASA have any documented procedures in the event of discovery of extraterrestrial life?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/3124/does-nasa-have-any-documented-procedures-in-the-event-of-discovery-of-extraterre)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Is there any non-rocket spacelaunch concept within reach of current material science and technology?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/3033/is-there-any-non-rocket-spacelaunch-concept-within-reach-of-current-material-sci)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 7, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Did VentureStar technology lead anywhere?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/3005/did-venturestar-technology-lead-anywhere)

**Net Score: -3** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 3)

---

Answer (score 3):

My notes from lowest to highest evaluation score:

- [Did VentureStar technology lead anywhere?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/3005/did-venturestar-technology-lead-anywhere)

  Link only answers tend not to be ideal for Stack Exchange sites.  In this case, a little explanation of how the fuel tank result found behind the link relates to the question.  Were the researchers part of the VentureStar program?  How much did the design deviate?  Key quotations from the linked material would also help in case the link rots.
- [Is there any non-rocket spacelaunch concept within reach of current material science and technology?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/3033/is-there-any-non-rocket-spacelaunch-concept-within-reach-of-current-material-sci)

  It's not a good sign when the question itself links to better answer than anything on the site.  It's not really the fault of the answers as much as the question.  Wikipedia has a chart with a bunch of NRS solutions and their [technological readiness level](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technology_readiness_level).  I'd be willing to bet these are meticulously vetted.  The top answer here is the [space gun](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_gun) (TRL 6).  The other answer mentions Orion (arguable not an answer) and mass drivers (TRL 2).  Nobody mentioned [ram acceleration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ram_accelerator) (TRL 6).  This question really needs improvement to achieve the goal of making the internet a better place to get your Space Exploration questions answered.
- [Does NASA have any documented procedures in the event of discovery of extraterrestrial life?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/3124/does-nasa-have-any-documented-procedures-in-the-event-of-discovery-of-extraterre)

  The answer might be right, but it's really speculative.  ALH84001 is not a bad precedent to cite, but that's the only case we know about.  Other NASA administrators and presidential staffs might develop different protocols.  It seems odd that nobody mentioned [SETI Institute's policy recommendations](http://www.seti.org/seti-institute/project/details/seti-and-policy).
- [How are fuel leaks discovered on a rocket?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/2987/how-are-fuel-leaks-discovered-on-a-rocket)

  - answer stub
  - bear bullets
  - could be filled out
- [Can I derive a combined equation for velocity of solar sail?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/2997/can-i-derive-a-combined-equation-for-velocity-of-solar-sail)

  Turns up as the fourth result for [solar sail velocity](https://www.google.com/search?q=solar+sail+velocity).  I can't vouch for Richard Hansen's math, but it looks like an ideal answer to the question.  Excellent.
- [Could electricity propel Curiosity on Venus?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/3037/could-electricity-propel-curiosity-on-venus)

  Fourth result of [curiosity on venus](https://www.google.com/search?q=curiosity+on+venus).  But that's rather specific.  I would have searched [rover on venus](https://www.google.com/search?q=rover+on+venus) which pointed me to the [Zephyr proposal](http://www.nasa.gov/directorates/spacetech/home/feature_windsurfing.html), which is looking at wind propultion.  Overall, I rate this question as Satisfactory.
- [Conjunction analysis for deep space missions](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/3067/conjunction-analysis-for-deep-space-missions)

  Good question, and good answer, but it's hard to search for via Google without using the words in the title.  For obvious reasons, most articles focus on Earth impacts or the [Deep Impact probe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_Impact_(spacecraft)).  It's fine for the site to have these questions, but they aren't Excellent according to the evaluation criteria.
- [How long does it take for a satellite to reach GEO?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/2914/how-long-does-it-take-for-a-satellite-to-reach-geo)

  My searches pointed to the SpaceX Falcon 9 v1.1 mission, but I couldn't find this site's question on the first page of results.
- [At what angle did Apollo 13 need to reenter?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/3058/at-what-angle-did-apollo-13-need-to-reenter)

  A fine answer, which is easily discoverable via Google.  So is the [passage quoted](http://books.google.com/books?id=LDJ43xYxK5YC&pg=PA258&lpg=PA258&dq=apollo+13+reentry+angle#v=onepage&q=apollo%2013%20reentry%20angle&f=false) from Lovell and Kluger.  It's nice that the answer here slightly corrected the quotation on its way by.  Excellent overall.
- [Do lunar landers communicate with ground stations during descent and landing?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/3134/do-lunar-landers-communicate-with-ground-stations-during-descent-and-landing)

  Fourth again when searching [lunar lander communication](https://www.google.com/search?q=lunar+lander+communication).  Another excellent result.

### Summary

Overall, this site is cruising along well.  There's good content and people are finding it via search.   It's still small and not growing much, so we're just waiting for the second stage to kick in.  Keep asking questions.  Be sure to go back and fill in answers that don't meet your usual standards.

Answer (score -1):

The question [Does NASA have any documented procedures in the event of discovery of extraterrestrial life?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/3124/does-nasa-have-any-documented-procedures-in-the-event-of-discovery-of-extraterre) has one answer that is incomplete or incorrect. On Google search I find [Brookings Report](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brookings_Report) which should have been mentioned.

Comment: That was a study of implications, not a procedure. There have been some studies on implications, and if you think they are worth mentioning you should write your own answer.